# Difference between count() value and foreach() cycles count

Tags: php, loops, foreach, count

All right, this is beyond my imagination. I must be missing something obvious, but I can't find, what.

a) PHP script:

```
echo('<pre>count($connectionsData) = '.print_r(count($connectionsData), TRUE).'</pre>');

$cnt = 0;

foreach($connectionsData as $connection)
{
    echo('<pre>'.(++$cnt).'. '.print_r($connection, TRUE).'</pre>');
}
```

b) result:

```
count($connectionsData) = 1

1. 1
2. 1
3. 8
4. 1
```

How it is possible, that `count` returns `1` (**one**) on some variable and then, when the very same variable is put into `foreach`, that loop cycles actually **four** times?

Comment: using brackets with echo hurts my brain. Regarding the question, can you reproduce this anywhere (eg http://codepad.viper-7.com/)

Comment: Is `connectionsData` is array or object?

Comment: I'm getting the right value with this code

Comment: @gbestard how, you dont know what `$connectionsData` is.

Comment: @user574632 I supposed it was an array though it could, and probably will, be an object

Comment: Is `$connectionsData` an `object` that extends  `array`?

Comment: What type and/or class name does `var_dump($connectionsData)` show?

Comment: Hi trejder, can you include the output of the value of $connectionsData?  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, folks for not giving so obvious information. As most of you predicted, `$connectionsData` is an object, not an array. The `var_dump` result won't give you anything, because it returns class (object) name, used internally by my project (ActiveRecord object).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `$connectionsData` is an object that does not implement the [countable interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php):

```
class Obj{
    public $var = 1;
    public $var2 = 2;

}

$obj = new Obj();

echo 'count: ' . count($obj) . '<br>';

$count=0;
foreach($obj as $el){
    echo ++$count . ' element: ' . $el . '<br>';
}

class CountableObj implements Countable{
    public $var = 1;
    public $var2 = 2;
    public function count(){ 
        return 2; 
    } 

}

$obj = new CountableObj();

echo 'count countable: ' . count($obj) . '<br>';

$count=0;
foreach($obj as $el){
    echo ++$count . ' element: ' . $el . '<br>';
}
```

live example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/q7sNol

Comment: Many thanks for answering may question, even without enough information! :]